# StringBuilder crash with ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I have a crash in Event Viewer with this:

```
Exception Info: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
   at XXX.BrainActions+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<runApp>b__0(System.Object, 
System.EventArgs)
```

The offending code is this, why is StringBuilder causing this exception?

```
       Process process = new Process();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Themes.getInstance().getScriptPath();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += new EventHandler((object sender, System.EventArgs e) => {
                string consoleOutput = builder.ToString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(consoleOutput))
                {
                    Log.INFO("XXX", String.Format("Console output: {0}", builder.ToString()));
                }
                processesRunning.Remove(process);
                if (callbacks != null)
                {
                    callbacks.ActionCompleted(action);
                    if (processesRunning.Count == 0)
                    {
                        callbacks.AllActionsCompleted();
                    }
                }
            });
            process.Start();
            process.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => builder.Append(args.Data);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => builder.Append(args.Data);
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            processesRunning.Add(process);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

StringBuilder is used to basically get the output of the external process and log it to the console using Log4net which is basically wrapped in the Log() function. Any ideas? Note that this crash rarely happens I've only seen it once but once is a reason to fix it.

Comment: Tip: StringBuilder is not a thread safe.

Comment: Thanks I've wrapped the object 'builder' within a lock now.

Comment: Can you let me know if that fixes it? Other posts on here sight multi-threading as the problem.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce the problem, but googling shows that it is a concurrency issue as you said. So using lock should solve the problem. I'm confident it should be fixed